# Alternative for the Registering ASP.NET 4.5 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012, aspnet-regiis.exe

I am getting MIME is not registered error when I run WCF service. I used this [link](http://3water.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/host-wcf-in-iis8-windows-server-2012/) to resolve this issue. After that I started getting another error which asked me to register the ASP.NET framework with IIS. So I used **"aspnet_regiis"** command for it but it shows me following error.

```
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.17929
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.17929).
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administr
ators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Win
dows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.e
xe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlin
k/?LinkID=216771.
Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.17929).
```

I tried to install/uninstall ASP.Net 4.5 from the server. But after doing that, my server was not started again and it always show the black screen. So I have to install the WS 2012 again. Can somebody explain me how to register ASP.NET with IIS again on WS 2012?

Comment: I have resolved this issue. I am posting the answer.

Comment: @Zeezer I have updated the answer. Please try it.

Comment: Thanks, but managed to bypass it somhow

Comment: My problem was related to BizTalk and ESB toolkit. So it has nothing to do with this, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we have to uninstall the 4.5 which comes under the Server roles not features. I am also attaching screen for the reference.

For this open the Server manager -> Dashboard -> 2) Roles and Features and follow the following steps which are mentioned in screenshots.

**Note: I am showing you how to Add Roles and Features wizard (install new features/roles) but if you want to uninstall/remove (uninstall new features/roles) then you have to click on “Start the Remove Roles and Features Wizard”. Please make sure that, first we have to install IIS and then .NET framework.**

[image] 
[image]

Select the server

[image]

You have to check ASP.NET 3.5 and ASP.NET 4.5 (based on requirement) options for register the .NET framework with IIS.

[image]

To install any features/roles, we have to check that option which we want to install. For uninstall any features/roles you have to uncheck it.

Please find the reference links below.

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/installing-iis-8-on-windows-server-2012

Comment: If you've ticked the option not to show the first screen of this wizard, then finding the Remove Wizard becomes quite hard (until you know). It's in Server Manager, under Manage menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried this once before on a Server Core Installation with the GUI installed. Similar to what the original poster saw I was Dropped into a Black Screen. not sure if he saw the same thing, but you can recover from this by reinstalling the GUI instead of starting a clean install. On 2012, Uninstall .NET 4.5 as a last resort, and if you completey remove all .net, don't be surprised to see the Command prompt on reboot. For help on GUI re installation see:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140618170857-12975178-procedure-to-recover-gui-in-windows-2012-and-2012r2-net-framework-feature-dependency-in-windows-2012-2012-r2