# register aspnet with IIS 8 in Windows 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis

I have installed visual studio before **installing IIS on Windows 2012**. When I try to run web application on IIS webserver, it says unable to debug on the web server.

Then I tried to re-register aspnet `using aspnet_regiis -r`, but as this is **deprecated** I tried to follow

[Alternative for the Registering ASP.NET 4.5 on Windows Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495429/alternative-for-the-registering-asp-net-4-5-on-windows-server-2012)

but the application development node is not available in roles section. I also tried to use DISM command to download. But that too failed.

Is there a workaround to register the ASP.NET in **IIS8** apart from these?

Comment: what if you use the VS menu Debug->Attach->w3wp.exe route, can you attach and debug your application?