# Configuration Error - targetFramework

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-8.5

Getting this error:

> The 'targetFramework' attribute in the  element of the
>   Web.config file is used only to target version 4.0 and later of the
>   .NET Framework (for example, '').
>   The 'targetFramework' attribute currently references a version that is
>   later than the installed version of the .NET Framework. Specify a
>   valid target version of the .NET Framework, or install the required
>   version of the .NET Framework.
>        Source File: E:\website.com\dir\dir\web.config    Line: 34
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1069.1

The line referenced in the error message is:

```
 <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
```

When I look up the solution to this error all I find are thing that say that the framework referenced in the code isn't installed on the server, but as you can see the ASP.Net Version and the targetFramework are both 4.6.1.  Any Ideas?

Comment: What happens if you change it to 4.5.1 or 4.5? Als you could try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35068802/5836671

Comment: The application comes up if I change the targetFramework to 4.5. In fact we have other applications on the same server running under that framework.  The only thing I can think of to do is uninstall and reinstall 4.6.1.

Comment: @JenniferKillingsworth Were you able to resolve this issue? :o